# PHP Regex: Replace anything that isn't a dot or a digit?

Tags: regex

I'm trying to see if a string is an IP address. Since IPv6 is rolling out it's better to support that too, so to make it simple, i just want to replace anything that isn't a dot or a number.

I found this regex on stackoverflow by searching:

```
\d+(?:\.\d+)+
```

but it does the opposite of what i want. Is it possible to inverse that regex pattern?

Thanks!

Comment: How does replacing everything that's not a dot or a number help with IPv6 compliance?

Comment: Oh i should've gone more in depth. What i mean is that i want to support both IPv4 and IPv6, and the simplest way to do that is to only match strings that contain numbers and dots, since that's what IP's are made of.

Comment: Uh, no? [IPv6 addresses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_address) are made of hexadecimal digits and the separator is a colon.

Comment: Oh god... well, at least you saw it before the site went live!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following:

```
[^.0-9]+
```

Matches anything that is not a dot or a number

Comment: If you guys are still there, i made a mistake! I want to include characters as well. :/

Answer (score 5):

This regex will match anything that isn't a dot or a digit:

```
/[^\.0-9]/
```

Answer (score 0):

I might try something like this  (untested):
**Edit:**
Old regex was way off, this appears to do better (after testing):
find: `.*?((?:\d+(?:\.\d+)+|))`
replace: `$1`

do globally, single line.

In Perl: `s/.*?((?:\d+(?:\.\d+)+|))/$1/sg`

Answer (score -1):

Regex shortcuts are case sensitive. I think you were trying to do something like this, but what you want is capital D
   `[\D] = any non-digit.`

in php it looks like this:

```
preg_replace('/[\D]/g', '', $string);
```

javascript its like this:

```
string.replace(/[\D]/g, '');
```

Comment: OP's request was that it didn't replace periods.